# Workflow - Email body of blog post (width control)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, email, html

I am using a workflow to email several users when a blog post is published (on sharepoint), this email includes the body of the blog post. This information comes from a lookup.

My email is *width="600"* and centered on the screen.

The blog post's body includes images, these images are automatically inserted in the body of email as intended. However, depending on the size of these images they brute force  the width of my email to match the image size.

Is there anyway I can stop this from happening? Is the only way around this telling the user to upload smaller images (width: height)?

Please comment if you need clarification.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try including the inline CSS to the body of the email. Use the max-width property for images inside the body's div. 
For ex. if you blog post body's div has a class 'ms-BlogPost' add css as:

```
<style type='text/css'>
  div.ms-BlogPost img {max-width: 600px; }
</style>
```

Comment: View the source code of the email to see if the url/src of the image is correct.